# Formatting Errors in GraphQL + NestJS

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-client

Im using NestJS to build a GraphQL server. I want all the errors of my api to have an internationalized message (using a lang header sent by the browser). I'm having some trouble with exceptions that I don't throw explicitly. In particular, I'm having problems with BAD_USER_INPUT errors caused by validations errors of GraphQL. I would like to do something similar to what is done [here](https://nestjs-i18n.com/guides/dto_validation/global-validation) with global validation of nestjs-i18n with class validator. I thought about using an Exception Filter to catch BAD_USER_INPUT and use nestjs-i18n on them to format the response to the client. However, when I receive the error, it looks like the following

```
 {
        "message": "Variable \"$input\" got invalid value \"hello\" at \"input.id\"; Value is not a valid UUID: hello",
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 37
            }
        ],
        "extensions": {
            "code": "BAD_USER_INPUT"
        }
    }
```

Off course, the message contains everything I need to know where the error is located (field, value and constraint failed) but it is in an inconvenient format . Is there any built in way in NestJs to have this info in a more convenient format? For example
I've seen sometimes that there is a path property with the path of the field that failed a validation. Or should I just try to parse the message and extract the info from it? Is this the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, as of the latest production build, NestJs does not count with the capability to cover that use case. I would suggest you change to a more flexible engine like express.